# Why and when to omit server header from HTTP response?

Tags: php, apache, http, ubuntu, webserver

I will probably work on project for `abc.com` hosted under `xyz.abc.com`. When I visit `xyz.abc.com`, the response contains the `server` header and I can know that it is Apache2 running on Ubuntu OS (`Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu)`). But when I visit `abc.com` and navigate on it, there is no `server` header in any of the responses.

Any explanations on this behaviour?

Is the `server` header presence controllable via Apache configuration or via programming ( in PHP it is possible to set last-modified for example)? if it is via directive, it means there are different instances of Apache for the separate domains (one is configured to return the header and the other one is configured to hide it)?

Or it is possible to use Ubuntu/Apache2 for `xyz.abc.com` and completely different technology stack for `abc.com`? what is the name of this technique?

Could you please explain the different possibilities for a newbie? thank you in advance.

Comment: Different domain names can be served by entirely different servers with nothing in common.  Also learn about reverse proxies like nginx.

Comment: Hi @SLaks, what I know is that reverse proxies serve for HTTP caching. Do they also allow separating technologies or is it only nginx that has this additionnal feature?

Comment: the server header is entirely optional. A webserver is **NOT** required to identify what software is producing the page. And such things can also be configured on a per-vhost basis as well. just because site "x" reveals the information has absolutely NO bearing on the sites "y", "z", etc... hosted on the same physical server.

Comment: This will be closed as too broad I suspect - but, in short, it's the Internet **everything** lies to you... possibly even me, right now O_o

Comment: It is configurable and a good recommendation to remove. It can be used to easily fingerprint your OS and services. For example I now know you have Apache 2.2.22 on Ubuntu and a quick Google gives me https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/vendor_id-45/product_id-66/version_id-142323/Apache-Http-Server-2.2.22.html metasploit will do this for an attacker.

Comment: @whitelettersinblankpapers: Most reverse proxies can route different URLs to different servers.

Comment: @MarcB, thank you I completely see your point now.  here is my final understanding :  `xyz.abc.com` and `abc.com`  are just two separate folders of PHP scripts (not necessarily subfoler one to another), they can be served by different technologies on different vhosts/or machines by different technology stacks

Comment: @nerdlyist, thank you that remove a part of my confusion. Website owner did this security measure for the first site, but not yet for the second. But that doesn't they both use same technology based on MarcB answer

Comment: @SLaks thank you very much Sir, this removes all confusions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding httpd, there is no option to remove the Server response header by official means.

Officially the most you can do through configuration is to set these directives:

```
ServerTokens Prod
ServerSignature off
```

With this, your Server response header will just say "Apache". And this is the most recommended thing to do.

Although if you have some paranoid audit which insists on having you remove the header completely, you have some "third-party" methods, the most well-known, at lease for me, is using "mod_security".

There is a third option, that is to modify Apache HTTPD source code yourself and compile it so it will not add the response header, but I doubt anyone would recommend you to do that.

In any case and answering your main question, removing that header does not really add any security to your server, so there is really no reason to remove it.